# What class structure allows for a base class and mix/match of subclasses? (Similar to Users w/ roles)

Tags: java, class-design, groovy, grails

I have a set of base characteristics, and then a number of sub-types. Each instance *must* be one of the sub-types, but can be multiple sub-types at once. The sub-types of each thing can change. In general, I don't care what subtype I have, but sometimes I do care.

This is much like a Users-Roles sort of relationship where a User having a particular Role gives the user additional characteristics. Sort of like duck-typing (ie. If my `Foo` has a `Bar`, I can treat it like a `ThingWithABar`.)

Straight inheritance doesn't work, since that doesn't allow mix/match of sub-types. (ie. no multi-inheritance).

Straight composition doesn't work because I can't switch that up at runtime.

How can I model this?

Answer (score 4):

What you want are *Interfaces.*

Each interface can mandate a characteristic.  A class can implement multiple interfaces as it pleases:

```
interface Foo {
  boolean doFoo();
}

interface Bar {
  boolean doBar();
}

class fooImpl implements Foo {
  boolean doFoo(){
    . . .
  }

}

class barImpl implements Bar {
  boolean doBar(){
    . . .
  }

}

class fooBarImpl implements Foo, Bar {
  boolean doFoo(){
    . . .
  }
  boolean doBar(){
    . . .
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, implement the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).  One state would be HasABar, and would provide the desired behavior for when your Foo has a Bar.  Another state might be HasABat, providing different behavior.  Your Foo object may start with HasNothing, until you give it a Bar, which would change the state to HasABar.

```
interface FooState {
   Drink getDrink() throws InvalidStateException;
}

class HasNothing implements FooState {
   Foo foo;

   HasNothing(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }   

   Drink getDrink() throws InvalidStateException {
      throw new InvalidStateException("There's no Bar");
   }
}

class HasABar implements FooState {
   Foo foo;

   HasABar(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }   
   Drink getDrink() throws InvalidStateException{
      Foo foo.getBar().getDrink();
   }
}

class Foo {
   FooState state;
   Bar bar;

   public Foo() {
      state = new HasNothing(this);
  }

   Bar getBar() {
      return bar;
   }

   void setBar(Bar bar) {
      this.Bar = bar;
      if (null != bar) {
         state = new HasABar(this);
      }
      else {
         state = new HasNothing(this);
      }
   }

   Drink getDrink() throws InvalidStateException{
         return state.getDrink();
   }
}
```

At this point you are not really dealing with subtypes, you've got one type that behaves differently depending on state during runtime.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for Interfaces because those are locked in at compile time and I need something that can change at runtime as my parent `Foo` changes from being a `Bar` to a `Baz`. Also, Interfaces require each concrete class to implement functionality/data-structure, which is the _opposite_ of what I want.

Comment: The update seems much more along the lines of what I'm after. But it would require that `Foo` know all of the possible "behaviors" (or States), which seems a bit inverted. However, it is much closer to what I'm after than plain Interfaces.

Comment: It doesn't really need to know the behaviors as such--just that there's something that it might want to do if it was in a certain state.  The states might also support differing behavior for other activites as well:  relax() could return "Just chillin'" for the HasNothing state and "Chillin' by the bar" for the HasABar state.  The interface is defined by foo, but the behavior is defined by the state.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your main class, User.  Then have it contain a list of objects, call them Role instances or implementations.  Your Role's all have to look alike to the User so it can talk to them, but their implementations can be very different.  (And in fact they can have powers (methods) the User knows nothing about.  Each just has to be Role, whatever else might be.)  Essentially, when the User is told to do something that it cannot do itself, directly, it will go through the list asking each Role if it can do it.  When it finds one that can, it calls that Role's `doIt` method.  And you can swap Role instances in and out of the User at any time.

The User might want to pass a Role instance back to a caller, because the caller might know that a Role with an ID of 6 implements the DatabaseReader interface and has methods the User object knows nothing about.

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but hopefully this will give you some ideas, even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for. How would I go about asking each `Role` if they can `doIt`?

Comment: @cdeszaq:  Ideally each role has a doIt method that does the job that role does in the way that role is supposed to do it.  Each different Role instance can have a different method.  Alternatively, the role--or something provided by the role--can be passed back to whatever called the User.  The caller may know a lot more about the Role or the information or contacts it provides than the User does.

Comment: So almost like a template method pattern. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

One way to do this is to a mapping table in a database to map users to allowed permissions, and create a db function to check permissions and add that to the beginning of any db request that requires permissions. This allows run time editing of roles and arbitrary permissions for each user.

Comment: Right, that's the most basic level of it, but the issue is when each "role" gives the "user" object (in code) additional fields and methods. The "extra stuff" for each role is what I'm trying to get. Plain vanilla Roles are easy.